# Fable implement foreign interface compile errors

Tags: f#, fable-f#

**TL;DR:**
I am trying to create a foreign interface, but I get compile errors. My F# skills are not yet equal to the task.

---

I have written a Photoshop script and now I am trying to convert that script to Fable (F#) for my own F# practise.

*Sidenote: I am very new to F# but I have a good C# background.*

To use the photoshop script library I need to define it as foreign interfaces (http://fable.io/docs/interacting.html). I am trying to implement a small class first for testing purposes. Namely the UnitValue class (see https://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/indesign/pdfs/JavaScriptToolsGuide_CS5.pdf p.230)

My attempt:

```
#r "node_modules/fable-core/Fable.Core.dll"

open System
open Fable.Core

[<Global>]
module Photoshop =
    [<Erase;StringEnum>]
    type PSUnit =
        | [<CompiledName("in")>] Inches
        | [<CompiledName("ft")>] Feet
        | [<CompiledName("yd")>] Yards
        | [<CompiledName("mi")>] Miles
        | [<CompiledName("mm")>] Millimeters
        | [<CompiledName("cm")>] Centimeters
        | [<CompiledName("m")>] Meters
        | [<CompiledName("km")>] Kilometers
        | [<CompiledName("pt")>] Points
        | [<CompiledName("pc")>] Picas
        | [<CompiledName("tpt")>] TraditionalPoints
        | [<CompiledName("tpc")>] TraditionalPicas
        | [<CompiledName("ci")>] Ciceros
        | [<CompiledName("px")>] Pixels
        | [<CompiledName("%")>] Percent

    type PSUnitValue =
        abstract ``as``: PSUnit -> float
        abstract ``value``: float with get, set
        abstract ``type``: PSUnit with get, set    

    let UnitValue : PSUnitValue = jsNative

open Photoshop

let test = new UnitValue();
test.``value`` = 12.0;
test.``type`` = Unit.Centimeters

Console.WriteLine (test.``as`` PSUnit.Millimeters)
```

During compilation I get:

```
C:\PsScripts>fable test.fsx
fable-compiler 0.7.28: Start compilation...
F# project contains errors:
C:\PsScripts\test.fsx(L35,15) : error FSHARP: The type 'UnitValue' is not defined
C:\PsScripts\test.fsx(L36,0) : error FSHARP: Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.
C:\PsScripts\test.fsx(L37,0) : error FSHARP: Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.
C:\PsScripts\test.fsx(L37,21) : error FSHARP: The field, constructor or member 'Centimeters' is not defined
C:\PsScripts\test.fsx(L39,19) : error FSHARP: Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.
C:\PsScripts\test.fsx(L39,0) : error FSHARP: A unique overload for method 'WriteLine' could not be determined based on type information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed. Candidates: Console.WriteLine(buffer: char []) : unit, Console.WriteLine(format: string, [<ParamArray>] arg: obj []) : unit, Console.WriteLine(value: bool) : unit, Console.WriteLine(value: char) : unit, Console.WriteLine(value: decimal) : unit, Console.WriteLine(value: float) : unit, Console.WriteLine(value: float32) : unit, Console.WriteLine(value: int) : unit, Console.WriteLine(value: int64) : unit, Console.WriteLine(value: obj) : unit, Console.WriteLine(value: string) : unit, Console.WriteLine(value: uint32) : unit, Console.WriteLine(value: uint64) : unit
```

My expected output would be something like:

```
var test = new UnitValue();
test.value = 12;
test.unit = "cm";
console.log(test.as("mm"));
```

---

For those who would like to know how the `UnitValue` class looks and don't want to look it up in the pdf, here I defined it in C#:

```
public class UnitValue
{
    // Static baseUnit not yet implemented in Fable
    public static UnitValue baseUnit { get; set; }

    // Constructors not yet implemented in Fable
    public UnitValue(float value, string unit) { }
    public UnitValue(string valueUnit) { }

    public string type { get; set; }
    public float value { get; set; }

    public float @as(string unit) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    // I don't use convert in my scripts, so not yet implemented in Fable as well
    public UnitValue convert(string unit) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You are binding a variable `UnitValue`, not declaring an alias for a type (not sure if that was the intent).
- types and values, just like in C# have different scopes, so as far as compiler is concerned the type is not declared.
- `jsNative` is just a shorthand for "throw", it's intended for imported JS constructs, but you are not importing any. See http://fable.io/docs/interacting.html
- since JS lacks types, if the interop is the intent, you actually have to define the type in F# yourself.
- if interop is not an intent, then write a normal F# code, without any Fable attributes, fable will take care of the rest.

Adding the comment answer here for the formatting:
UnitValue needs to be a function (constructor):

```
let UnitValue : unit->PSUnitValue = jsNative
```

then you could call it:

```
let test = UnitValue()
```

Also checkout [this post](https://thoughtspam.wordpress.com/2017/01/10/authoring-fable-bindings-inheritance-and-variance-in-action) for a bit of a background on bindings.

Comment: If I check http://fable.io/docs/interacting.html#Foreign-interfaces then StringDecoder is also written as: `let StringDecoder: NodeStringDecoder = jsNative` same way I am doing it. And under the Import attribute (http://fable.io/docs/interacting.html#Import-attribute) it is stated that `If the module or value is globally accessible in JavaScript, you can use the Global attribute without parameters instead.`

Comment: The `UnitValue` js-type is not defined in a file, it is just globally accessible in my photoshop js script. Therefor I use the `Global` attribute. To use the `UnitValue` in Fable I need to write a 'facade' for it. As I understood the documentation, I needed to create a Foreign Interface. I based my code on the sample in the documentation.

Comment: And as you can see, my intent is not to have the `Photoshop` module in the output at all, please see my desired output for my intent.

Comment: I see where the confusion comes from, `UnitValue` needs to be a function (constructor):
    let UnitValue : unit->PSUnitValue = jsNative
then you could call it:
    let test = UnitValue()

Answer (score 1):

With the help from [Eugene Tolmachev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/435174/):

Working(ish) code:

```
#r "node_modules/fable-core/Fable.Core.dll"

open System
open Fable.Core

module Photoshop =
    [<StringEnum>]
    type PSUnit =
        | [<CompiledName("in")>] Inches
        | [<CompiledName("ft")>] Feet
        | [<CompiledName("yd")>] Yards
        | [<CompiledName("mi")>] Miles
        | [<CompiledName("mm")>] Millimeters
        | [<CompiledName("cm")>] Centimeters
        | [<CompiledName("m")>] Meters
        | [<CompiledName("km")>] Kilometers
        | [<CompiledName("pt")>] Points
        | [<CompiledName("pc")>] Picas
        | [<CompiledName("tpt")>] TraditionalPoints
        | [<CompiledName("tpc")>] TraditionalPicas
        | [<CompiledName("ci")>] Ciceros
        | [<CompiledName("px")>] Pixels
        | [<CompiledName("%")>] Percent

    type PSUnitValue =
        abstract ``as``: PSUnit -> float
        abstract ``value``: float with get, set
        abstract ``type``: PSUnit with get, set    
    let [<Global>] UnitValue : unit->PSUnitValue = jsNative

open Photoshop

let test = UnitValue();
test.``value`` <- 12.0;
test.``type`` <- PSUnit.Centimeters

Console.WriteLine (test.``as`` PSUnit.Millimeters)
```

**Output**

```
export var test = UnitValue(null);
test.value = 12;
test.type = "cm";
console.log(test.as("mm"));
```

I don't know what the `export` keyword is doing here, or why there isn't a `new` keyword for the UnitValue, but it compiled and looks in the direction of what I want....

Onwards!

---

I now have the `new` keyword in my output:

```
let [<Global;Emit("new $0($1, $2)")>] UnitValue (v: float) (t: PSUnit): IUnitValue = jsNative
```

And usage now is:

```
let test = UnitValue 12.0 PSUnit.Centimeters
Console.WriteLine (test.``as`` PSUnit.Millimeters)
```

Comment: because your implicit (main) module is `public` and the `let` binding is `public` fable declares it as `export`.

Comment: @EugeneTolmachev and do you have a pointer for me for the new keyword that is missing for the UnitValue?

Comment: Looks like UnitValue is a function, if so then there is no need for `new`

Comment: Except for the fact that in javascript it is an object. As stated, I am a F# noob, maybe I am doing something completly wrong?